# C# (WPF) DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf

I made 3 buttons programmatically, and added Click event to them inside for loop.

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; i++)
        {
          Button b = new Button();
          b.Name = "button " + i;
          b.Content = "20";
          b.Click+=new RoutedEventHandler(b_Click);
          st.Children.Add(b); //added to stack panel
        }
```

And when I click to any of these buttons, I want to decrease Button content by 1 every second. But I don't want to stop timer for previous button but instead If I click to all three buttons I want to see on every button content is decreasing by 1 every second (so if I click to one button only it's content is decreasing not all of them). 
Problem is that if I click to to one button and then to another the previous is stopped because there is only one timer and one tick method and I don't know how to change it. I want to add to b_Tick method  one counter that is decreasing every second and set that to sender's content. 
So if I click to first button content is decreasing every second and if I click to another button I want both their content to decrease every second, of course first button's content will continue, it will not reset.

I hope I was clear

Thanks

Comment: Your question really needs a better title. It shouldn't include information already in the tags (C# and WPF). It should explain the problem encountered, or what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just let the timer tick once a second. In the Tick check for every button if its content needs to be updated. For each Button you store if it should be decreasing and what the latest value is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary of timers keyed by button so each button has it's own timer.

```
private IDictionary<Button, Time> timersByButton = new Dictionary...()

for (int i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
  b = new Button();
  b.Name = "button " + i;
  b.Content = "20";
  timersByButton[b] = new Timer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
  b.Click+=new RoutedEventHandler(b_Click);
  st.Children.Add(b); //added to stack panel
}

private void b_Click(...)
{
   // Get button
   var timer = timersByButton[button];

   if (timer.Interval >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
   {
       timer.Interval = timer.Interval.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
   }
}
```

Comment: And how about that timer_Tick? how to decrease content value by 1 every second on every button when pressed without stoping previous?

Comment: You answered only half of my question. Please help me solve this

Comment: There is an Interval property on the Timer - sorry I'm not at a sensible browsing device so I'm guessing the api names from memory a little. So when you get the timer in the event handler, decrement the interval value on the timer. Check that it doesn't go less than 1 second though.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the Timer.Interval change. It is very crude but should give you a good idea of the process. I have arbitrarily set the timer to start with a 5 second delay.

Comment: When I click to button 1 it is decreasing by one but when I click to another button it decrease by two etc. I means that every time I click to the button more timers are pointing to same Method and I don't want it to happen. I simply want just this : if I click to all buttons, I want their content to decrease by one at same time not only one butten at time. Please help me solve this it's urgent. Thx

Comment: So ANY button click results in a one second reduction in the interval for ALL buttons?

Comment: first time it decreasing by one, than by two, than by 3 etc. Because on every button click the number of timers is increasing and all of them are pointing to one Tick method. So if I click to second button it Will decrease two times because tick method was started two times,  one time per timer..

Comment: In the Tick method check which timer fired the Tick - it will be the sender object. Then you can handled each one uniquely

Comment: I need to Cast sender to IDictionary<Button,DispatcherTimer>?

Comment: No, to Timer. When an even is raised in .Net, the sender are in the handler is always the instance that raised the event. It must be object as it can be anything.

Comment: Difference between timer's instances is HashCode so how can I see which timer of which button has fired the Tick?

Comment: As a quick fix maybe create a reverse dictionary so you can retrieve the button from the timer. Or as you only have three, enumerate the key value pairs of the dictionary and match on the Value which is the timer so the Key will be the Button

Comment: By all means post an expanded example. I'm just reacting to each problem rather than seeing the whole picture of the code